# CDK ApiGateway Lambda Canary Deployment 5xx Error Alarm

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I have a RestApi defined in CDK with API endpoints backed by lambda functions, and I'd like to do a canary / blue/green deployment where it rolls back any time a lambda function returns a 5xx response.

The way I have it set up now will cause a rollback if there are any function errors, but not if the lambda function returns a 500 response manually.

For example:

```js
// fooHandler.ts

export async function handler(event) {
  // Lambda function does not throw, so no "function error".
  return { statusCode: 500, body: 'Internal Server Error' };
}
```

```js
// apiStack.ts

class ApiStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: App, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const restApi = new RestApi(this, 'myRestApi', {
      restApiName: 'MyRestApi',
      deploy: true,
      deployOptions: { stageName: 'deployStage' },
      disableExecuteApiEndpoint: true
    });

    const application = new LambdaApplication(this, 'lambdaApp');

    const fooResource = restApi.root.addResource('foo');

    const fooFunction = new NodejsFunction(this, 'fooFunction', {
      entry: 'fooHandler.ts'
    });

    const fooFunctionAlias = new Alias(this, 'fooLiveAlias', {
      aliasName: 'live',
      version: fooFunction.currentVersion
    });

    const fooMethod = fooResource.addMethod('GET', new LambdaIntegration(fooFunctionAlias));

    const failureAlarm = new Alarm(this, 'fooFailureAlarm', {
      metric: fooFunctionAlias.metricErrors(),
      threshold: 1,
      evaluationPeriods: 1
    });

    const fooLambdaDeploymentGroup = new LambdaDeploymentGroup(this, 'fooDeployment', {
      alias: fooFunctionAlias,
      application,
      deploymentConfig: LambdaDeploymentConfig.CANARY_10PERCENT_5MINUTES,
      alarms: [failureAlarm]
    });
  }
}
```

This does work for catching the case where the handler function throws and ApiGateway's native error handling catches it and returns a 502 error, but if my lambda function code explicitly handles an error and returns a 5xx response on it's own, I can't figure out a way to catch that in a metric and rollback the deployment.

I do see that ApiGateway has a `5xxError` metric ([per the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html)) that I could use to create an alarm of when the function returns a 5xx error, but I don't see any metric dimensions that would allow my canary deployment to only trigger the alarm if the new function version (`currentVersion`) that the alias is pointing to returns the 5xx error; it seems that it would trigger the alarm even if the 5xx response is coming from the previous version.

```js
// Not sure whether there is any kind of dimension that would allow
// me to specify that I only want to alarm on the new version
// in the canary deployment
const serverErrorAlarm = new Alarm(this, 'ServerErrorAlarm', {
  metric: new Metric({
    namespace: 'AWS/ApiGateway',
    metricName: '5xxError',
    dimensionsMap: {
      ApiName: restApi.restApiName,
      Method: 'get',
      Resource: fooResource.path,
      Stage: restApi.deploymentStage.stageName
    }
  })
});
```

Alternatively, there is the `fooMethod.metricServerError(...)` metric method, but when I use it, I get a `Error [ValidationError]: Circular dependency between resources` error during deployment, so I'm not sure if it's appropriate for this use case.

Is this something that can be achieved?